# Is it possible to run Cucumber tests concurrently in Saucelabs?

Tags: cucumber, saucelabs

I've managed to get concurrent JUnit based tests running in Saucelabs using the Sauce ConcurrentParameterized JUnit runner (As described at https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Java+Test+Setup+Example#JavaTestSetupExample-RunningTestsinParallel). 
I'm wondering if there is a runner that achieves the same thing for Cucumber based tests?

Answer (score -1):

I don't there is such a runner.

The Cucumber runner is, as far as I know, single threaded and doesn't execute tests in parallel. But executing in parallel is just half of your problem, the other half is connecting to Saucelabs. And that is not supported by Cucumber.

My current approach if I wanted to execute on Saucelabs would be to use JUnit and live with the fact that I'm lacking the nice scenarios that Cucumber bring to the table. This doesn't mean that the JUnit tests couldn't use the same helpers as the Cucumber steps does.

Comment: As of v4 you can run features in parallel